# Best solution for an admin with few elements

Tags: website-design, menu, dashboard

I'm working on a user panel for the customers of my online store. For now I'm going to launch it with 4 sections, but in the future there will be more sections.

In mobile it looks very good:

[image]

But in the desktop version it is very poor because it has only 4 elements. very poor in terms of content:

[image]

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Can you try to formulate a real, specific question? Asking for advice is very fluffy and you'll get lower quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

a) if there is no good reason why not to display similar tiles in desktop version, then you could just display the same tiles (perhaps all 4 in 1 row)

b) if it's just a left menu and main content will be displayed after clicking on 1 of the items, then you might want to display the contents of the most important item (Profile?) by default (i.e. no empty screen)